# Openssl self signed certificates gets the "valid from date" with timezone UTC offset

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I create a test self signed certificate with openssl commad:
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -in xxx.csr -key xxx.key -out xxx.crt
the certificate  with the option to be valid for 365 days.
But time of execution of this command at say 10:04 am (Timezone is GMT+5.30)

Now when i use this certificate as the webserver SSL certificate, I get the error as 'The security certificate presented by this website has expired or is not yet valid."

In the certificate it has the "valid from date" is 3:34 pm .
It seems to add the timezone UTC interval is getting added to the current time.

Any clues?

Comment: Is your OS clock right?. Try by increasing the number of days say 100 years. After that check its validity period.

Comment: yes OS clock is correct. I've tried with 3650 days also, but same problem again.

Comment: What was the end time when you used 3650 days?

Comment: It was ten years exact

Comment: Old thread I know but did you figure it out? Running into same issue here with openssl cert validity being +0500 hours into the future because it is somehow using UTC rather than the system time